# Entity: automatic migration on Production not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have looked at other questions on SO and on blogs and official MS docs but I can't find the proper way.
What I am trying to achieve:

1. Deploy version 1 of an MVC website with SQL DB (code is based on Entity Code First v. 6.1), without any concept of migration because it's DB SCHEMA v.1
2. Deploy further versions (2, 3, ..) with automatic migration to SCHEMA v2 (and then v3 etc.) and **without running Update-Database** in Package Manager console

So, following MS tutorial (i.e. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx) version 1 creates tables for Schema v1:

- Blogs table with two columns (BlogId and Name)
- __MigrationHistory with one row (MigrationId contains InitialCreate). Not sure what this is about, but I guess it's the initial schema. Am I right?

Then I open Package Manager Console and I type: `Enable-Migrations` which creates classes for migration (201610091823367_InitialCreate.cs and Configuration.cs). I then modify the Blog class to have a new property Url as suggested in the tutorial and run `Add-Migration AddBlogUrl`, which creates 201610091830008_AddBlogUrl.cs

In addition, I added

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, Configuration>());
```

to the main, so when the application starts it should migrate automatically.
I launch the app v2, and everything is working perfectly. The Table has now the new column.

When I launch the app v2 again, it crashes with exception:

> Unhandled exception: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an object named 'Blogs' in the database.` and all the related stack trace.

So it looks like it's not recognizing that it's in the DB there's the most recent schema, so it tries to create the table again. I have added a breakpoint to `InitialCreate` class, method `Up` and it is called. I am surprised!

I've tried also a different approach:

1. ran app v1
2. ran app v2b with `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` in the Configuration class. The outcome is the same.

Can anyone help me to understand what's wrong and what's the right approach?
Can you confirm that in the meantime I **am OK to deploy SCHEMA v1 without having enabled migrations at all**?

I was hoping that this kind of scenarios were covered by Entity.

Comment: When you explore the database after the migration, are there any tables left that existed in schema 1, but should not exist in schema 2 (or habe been renamed)?

Comment: First, you need to understand [how migrations work](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Under-the-Hood). To start using migrations with an existing database, you need to create an initial migration with a snapshot of what the schema currently looks like "add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges". The IgnoreChanges flag tells it not to update anything - just take the snapshot. Finally, I wouldn't use automatic migrations in a PROD environment.

Comment: @MatthiasJansen The problem was that the DB tables were created by EF and an entry in the __MigrationHistory was created (without having enabled migrations at all) called "YYYMMDDHHMMSS_InititalCreate". When I then was enabling migrations, a class called YYYMMDDHHMMSS_InititalCreate was created but the timestamp were different, therefore the MigrationIDs were different. I found here on SO that the workaround was to rename the table with the MigrationId of the class, but it seems odd to me.

Comment: @SteveGreene I'll have a look the the website, but I thought I had a clear understanding so far. Why you wouldn't use automatic migration? So far, my testing loooks ok. The alternative being generating a script using Package Manager Console and running it manually?